# Куда ставить DFS namespace?

Tags: windows, dfs

Есть набор серверов:

- DC1 (windows 2012)
- DC2 (windows 2012)
- FS1 (windows 2008 r2)
- FS2 (windows 2008 r2)

Хочу поставить DFS. Будет репликация между FS1 и FS2. Куда ставить DFS namespace?

И еще вопрос. Допустим я ставлю dfs namespace на DC1. Все работает. Будет ли работать доступ при перезагрузке DC1? Если нет, то как это обойти? может ли поставить dfs namespace на DC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставил DFS namespace на DC1 и DC2. Объединил их ("Добавить сервер пространства имен..."). При перезагрузке одного из DC - доступ к пространству имен выполняется.